# CodeConditionStatement and Nullable.Equals

Tags: vb.net, code-generation, dblinq, dbmetal

I have to create the following VB.Net code through a C# CodeConditionStatement

```
If Not Nullable.Equals(field.Name, Value) Then
    ...
End If
```

What I alredy tried was

```cs
var property = new CodeMemberProperty();

CodeExpression condition = new CodeMethodInvokeExpression(System.Nullable,"Equals", new CodeExpression(){
                new CodeVariableReferenceExpression(field.Name),
                new CodePropertySetValueReferenceExpression()
            });

property.SetStatements.Add(new CodeConditionStatement(condition, null));
```

but a `System.Nullable` can't be converted in a CodeExpression.

Comment: You cannot use `System.Nullable(Of T).Equals` in the way that you are attempting: the code that you want to generate is invalid – no wonder that the generator refuses to generate that code.

Comment: That's why I'm searching a way to generate the Nullable.Equals function through a CodeConditionStatement that is working :D

Comment: That won’t work either. The code you want to call simply doesn’t exist. `Nullable` isn’t a complete class, it needs to be `Nullable(Of SomeType)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this seems to work:

```
property.SetStatements.Add(new CodeConditionStatement(
                new CodeSnippetExpression(String.Format("Not Nullable.Equals({0}, value)", field.Name)), 
                null));
```

pretty awful but working.....

If someone has a better idea :D